# Change colour of a cell based on it's formatting in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a Gant chart-like roster in Excel. The idea is to be able to quickly input the employee name along with their start and end time and have excel automatically calculate their shift length, required breaks, and colour in the required cells. The timing of breaks can then be decided so that there are no overlaps, no staff, etc. I've done all the automatic processes, using an IF function to insert a space into the time cells the employee is working and then using conditional formatting to make the cell green if it contains a space. This is what it looks like so far:

[image: Current Gant chart implementation]

My issue is trying to figure out how the breaks can subsequently be added in. I was hoping to be able to bold the relevant cell where the break will be and then have conditional formatting that changes the colour of the cell if it is bold. But it doesn't seem like this is something that can be done?

Is there a way either through using macros to do this, or some other method that will be easy to more or less visually 'select' when the breaks will be (rather than typing the break time in an additional cell and expanding the IF formula/conditional formatting)?

Answer (score 0):

You can start with conditional formatting, based on the following formula:

```
=AND(F$1>=$B2,F$1<=$C2)
```

The first results look as follows:

[image]

As far as the breaks are concerned, you can't create a conditional formatting, based on a format (like bold text), you'll need to create a formula for them and go from there.